# Laravel Users Query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, rdbms

In my app I have users that have members via a `members_of` field on the same `users` table. All users have a role of either User or Member. I need to grab all members with the `member_of` id equal to the `Auth->user()->id`

Here I can grab all the members with the role "member". But I'm not sure how to also grab only members where their `member_of` is equal to the logged in users id

```
$members = Role::where('name', 'member')->first()->users()->get();
```

So for example my DB looks like this... For example `Member11` belongs to `User10` via the `member_of` column.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`->users()` returns and instance of the `query builder`. This will allow you to chain a `->where()` clause.

```
 Role::where('name', 'member')->first()->users()->where('member_of', auth()->user()->id)->get();
```

That should do it.